# Payment Request API is not working on Chrome and Edge on desktop

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, microsoft-account, google-accounts

I am trying to test the new API 'Payment Request API', that is supported in the last half year by Chrome and Edge. there is a test page for it in this web page:
https://stripe.com/docs/payment-request-api

I am able to activate my payment method from my Android device but I can't activate it from my desktop, when using either Chrome or Edge.
Instead of 'Pay' button I get the message:

> Either your browser does not support the Payment Request API, or you
>   do not have a saved payment method. To try out the Payment Request
>   Button, switch to one of the supported browsers below, and make sure
>   you have a saved payment method.

Although I do have registered payment methods (credit cards) both in my Google and Microsoft accounts.

Why is this API not supported by *Chrome* and *Edge* as it was supposed to?

BTW, answer like - 'it works for me', is also acceptable.

Comment: I get the same error despite having a credit card added under "Payment Methods" in Chrome 76 settings screen.